# How does an increase in CO2 concentration affect Photosynthesis and Transpiration

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis, plant-anatomy, chloroplasts, plasma-membrane

I noticed a strange thing in my book. At one place it says that an increase in CO$_2$ concentration in the outside air decreases the rate of transpiration but at the other place it says that an increase in the level of CO$_2$ in the environment increases the rate of photosynthesis?
Can we reconcile between these two statements? I don't think so because both the processes mostly take place through the stoma so how is it possible that when transpiration decreases photosynthesis increases ?How ?

Comment: great! could you please also link to the literature you are referring to?

Comment: @JordiZambrino i didn't get you ..... what do you mean by the literature i am using?

Comment: By literature I mean what book you are reading.

Comment: @JordiZambrino. .. i m using ICSE Concise Biology